# Connecting IBOutlet results in nsunknownkey exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uitableview

I know as soon as you read the title you must be thinking.. well thats pretty common but believe me I have been banging my head with this for past 2 days now. I have tried every solution mentioned in the stackoverflow and elsewhere I could find on the internet but nothing works. I even tried starting out my project afresh (luckily, I got stuck at very initial stage) but it still throws the same exception.

Here is a description of my problem. I have created a custom cell as a subclass of UITableViewCell (pretty usual eh). Now my view controller (in which a UITableView is added) registers the nib for my customcell in viewdidload.

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VideoCustomCell"
                                           bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseID"];
```

and at the cellForRowAtIndexPath I simply do a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.
So far so good. I fire up the project and everything runs proper. I can see my custom cell being loaded up in the tableview.

Problem starts when I connect any control from my custom cell to an IBOutlet. It throws `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0xa4b4fe0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key vidName.'`

Now I have tried all these:

- Changing the file owner of XIB to my custom cell class, to NSObject, to my view controller but no luck.
- Changing the name of my outlet (in case there might be a naming conflict) but still same result.
- Changing the "main interface" to different view controllers and leaving it blank as well but still nothing.
- I have even tried removing every other control except one label in my cell and it still throws the exception when I connect.

FYI.. My project is a universal project and I am using Xcode 5.

Update: cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";
VideoCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.vidName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Comment: Did you set the custom class name to the table view cell class that contains the property/variable "vidName"?

Comment: Post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and maybe we can see what's up there.

Comment: updated my question with the code..

Comment: Are you connecting to the file owner, or the cell view?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you properly. I am connecting the above mentioned label to the file owner which is my customcell class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered so far, it looks like you have the following setup:

- A storyboard with a UITableViewController and related table view controller class
- A Xib for the custom cell and you are registering using registerNib on the table view
- A custom cell class you use to set the vidName label text dynamically.

Am I missing anything?

So here are a few guidelines. When you create a Xib file for a table view cell, you set the cell instance in Interface Builder to the custom cell class--not the file's owner. Then, you connect the label outlet to your cell instance in interface builder. Like so:

[image]

Now the rest of your code should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VideoCustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseID"];
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate/DataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";
    VideoCustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.vidName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I posted a sample project here that might be able to help further: https://github.com/perlmunger/BasicTableViewCustomCell

Comment: "you set the cell instance in Interface Builder to the custom cell class--not the file's owner". This did it for me.. You are a life saver man ! But I still dont understand.. isn't file owner same as custom cell class?

Answer (score 2):

You need set same value to Restoration ID and Class.
[image]